# Update stats in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-performance

I have a big db in Oracle and I just deleted all the data from the database and I am going to re-insert a big amount of new data.

Should I run update stats on empty database? Is there a good source to read about when should I update the statistics on the tables and indexes?

Comment: There isn't much point gathering stats between the delete and insert, unless you're still expecting queries to be run - which would seem odd. Gathering manually after the insert might be sensible; are you also dropping and rebuilding indexes to speed up the insert?

Comment: I see some discrepancy here: you say that deleted all data from just one table and then ask about gathering statistics on empty database? The database should not be empty if you have more than one table. :) I guess you was meaning gathering statistics on just that empty table?

Comment: Sorry, was meant to be database, I am deleting a bunch of tables

Comment: Indexes are staying in place, it's a reinitialization of data, I have an app that generates the queries and I need it to run as quickly as possible. So, the question is - if I delete data will the previous stats make the queries run longer? And another question - if I gather stats on empty tables - will it make queries run longer when there is more data or stats will be updated as the data comes in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that at least in Oracle 10 Truncate [does not update stats](http://hemantoracledba.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/table-and-index-statistics-with.html). Oracle will plan its queries using the same plan as if the tables were full of data so it could try some inefficient execution plans.

I will recommend to update stats after bigs changes in the amount of data like migrations, ETL, etc.

In Oracle 11 has [improved the gathering of stats](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1133388300346992024) so things could be different.